# Grid cell shrinking when hovered over

Tags: html, css, hover, css-grid

How can I stop the grid shrinking when hovering over it, and stop the whole grid from change ?

Just a simple hover of the grid makes that effect, and I tried height and width 100%.

I cant figure out what's happening and where the issue is coming from, hover is on the div and not on the image. I could understand if the hover over the image was not working as the images are stretched to fit the div.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Centaur26/pen/BaWKeEm

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  height: 100%;
}
.block h1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  /* border:1px solid red; */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  /* background:  black; */

  grid-template-areas:
    "pic1 pic2 pic2 pic3 pic3"
    "pic1 pic4 pic5 pic3 pic3"
    "pic6 pic4 pic5 pic7 pic8"
    "pic6 pic9 pic10 pic7 pic8";
  gap: 2px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pic1 {
  grid-area: pic1;

  background-image: url(chess/Polgar.jpg);
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.pic2 {
  grid-area: pic2;
  background-image: url(chess/chess2.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.pic3 {
  grid-area: pic3;
  background-image: url(chess/tal1.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic4 {
  grid-area: pic4;
  background-image: url(chess/kasparov.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic5 {
  grid-area: pic5;
  background-image: url(chess/gary.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic6 {
  grid-area: pic6;
  background-image: url(chess/carlson.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic7 {
  grid-area: pic7;
  background-image: url(chess/ding.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic8 {
  grid-area: pic8;
  background-image: url(chess/girl.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic9 {
  grid-area: pic9;
  background-image: url(chess/hand.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pic10 {
  grid-area: pic10;
  background-image: url(chess/chess123.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

/* .pic1:hover{
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        color:white;
        width:100%;
        opacity: .1;
      
        border: 1px solid red;
} */

.pic2:hover p {
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

.pic1:hover p {
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Chess</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="chess.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="block">
         <h1>Chess Images</h1>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="pic1">
               <p>Judith Polgar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pic2">
               <p>Chess Board</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pic3"></div>
            <div class="pic4"></div>
            <div class="pic5"></div>
            <div class="pic6"></div>
            <div class="pic7"></div>
            <div class="pic8"></div>
            <div class="pic9"></div>
            <div class="pic10"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that it's shrinking because it hasn't been given a specific width and height for each columns and row so therefore it's shrinking to fit content. Not 100% sure but adding the below to the `.container` fixed it

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
```

Comment: ,, not having fixed dimensions could be the issue its an irregular grid with given grid-template-area,  I don't know how to set fixed dimensions for that..

Comment: Well if you just want it fixed and working properly then add the above code to your container where you assigned the grid areas.

Comment: @ Justin is it the case  that gird with relative dimensions lengths (e.g. percentage) don't work well with grid hover effect?

Comment: It actually works well: it fits the cells to the dimenstions of their content. When you hover, you change the content (font-size, border, width, height etc.), and thus the grid cell fits to the size of the new content. If you fix the grid cells size instead of asking them to adapt to the cell's content, they will no more resize when the content changes.

Comment: The grid is working well. The reason it is shrinking when you hover is because you are changing the position of the `<p>` to absolute thus removing it from the html flow. Now the grid re-adjusts itself to evenly distribute the grid again. Remove both `<p>` tags from the exmaple you gave above and see how the cells are aligned. Then add them back and hover and you will see they revert back to what they were without the `<p>` tags. That is because you just took the `<p>` out of the flow of html by positioning it absolutely in the `:hover`.

Comment: If you do not want any shifting of cells then tell it what size you want each one to be. If you have 5 columns then give each 20% of the grid.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, @Justin, I'm relatively new to grids, your solution is where I eventually ended up. First when I saw your response, because it was so straight forward(unlike the gird) I was thinking if you even saw the outcome. Well, it has fixed the issue and I'll remember this for future...thanks a lot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are changing the style of the `p` tag instead of `div` tag when hovering. I think the shrink is caused by `position`.
You can try this solution

```
    .pic1:hover {
   font-size: 17px;
   opacity: .7;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bolder;
   border-color: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   text-align: center;
}
```

Here I applied `hover` to `div` instead and removed `position` and `border`attributes.
However, it can cause the `div` to bigger when hovering because of the `font-size` change. You can set `min-width` to the `div` at the biggest size possible, for example

```
.pic1 {
     grid-area: pic1;

     background-image: url(chess/Polgar.jpg);
     position: relative;
     background-size: cover;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     min-width: 290px;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Linh, I assigned fixed width to each cell in the grid and distributed the the grid items for specific outcome, thanks for your feedback.